# With regard to site definitions what is the default value of the enableTracking attribute?

Tags: site-configuration

This may seem like a really obvious question, but I just wanted to make sure as I couldn't find any documentation on this particular attribute.

Within the site definitions `<site>` there is an attribute called `enableTracking`:

For example:

```
<site name="service" enableTracking="true" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service" />
```

I am wondering if this attribute is defaulted to true if it is not present?

Does it determine if an individual site has XDB tracking enabled / disabled?  Or does it have another purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the default setting for a site is `true` if not set. This will of course be overridden by the global setting.

```
namespace Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking
{
    public class TrackingSiteContext
    {
        public TrackingSiteContext (SiteInfo siteInfo)
        {
            this.SiteInfo = siteInfo;
        }

        public bool EnableTracking
        {
            get
            {
                bool flag = true;
                bool result;
                if (bool.TryParse (this.SiteInfo.Properties["enableTracking"], out result))
                    flag = result;
                return flag;
            }
        }

        protected SiteInfo SiteInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked the following question to Sitecore support and the answer was:

> This setting literally defines whether analytics tracking is enabled for a site or not.
>
> For some sites tracking can be excessive
> functionality, therefore this parameter allows disabling it in a handy
> way on a site level.
>
> You can enable it globally but disable for
> specific sites by this setting.

Comment: But what is the default? Assuming true now, but is that a correct assumption?

Comment: @Gatogordo I think the default would be the global setting if the `enableTracking` is not set. It will fallback to the global one.

Comment: Correct, based on the answer I believe it is true by default.